error in line roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557" Unknown substitution command [find-pkg-share mavros]
This is the error message I'm getting
rohanshenoy30@rohanubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557"
... logging to /home/rohanshenoy30/.ros/log/f9bfea92-39e4-11ef-9bb3-994f588e7125/roslaunch-rohanubuntu-141145.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

RLException: Unknown substitution command [find-pkg-share mavros]. Valid commands are ['find', 'env', 'optenv', 'dirname', 'anon', 'arg']
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

This is my px4.launch file
<include file="$(find-pkg-share mavros)/launch/node.launch">
    <arg name="pluginlists_yaml" value="$(find-pkg-share mavros)/launch/px4_pluginlists.yaml" />
    <arg name="config_yaml" value="$(find-pkg-share mavros)/launch/px4_config.yaml" />
    <arg name="fcu_url" value="$(var fcu_url)" />
    <arg name="gcs_url" value="$(var gcs_url)" />
    <arg name="tgt_system" value="$(var tgt_system)" />
    <arg name="tgt_component" value="$(var tgt_component)" />
    <arg name="log_output" value="$(var log_output)" />
    <arg name="fcu_protocol" value="$(var fcu_protocol)" />
    <arg name="respawn_mavros" value="$(var respawn_mavros)" />
    <arg name="namespace" value="$(var namespace)"/>
</include>

This is my node.launch file
<node pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" name="mavros" namespace="$(arg namespace)" output="screen">
    <param name="fcu_url" value="$(arg fcu_url)"/>
    <param name="gcs_url" value="$(arg gcs_url)"/>
    <param name="tgt_system" value="$(arg tgt_system)"/>
    <param name="tgt_component" value="$(arg tgt_component)"/>
    <param name="fcu_protocol" value="$(arg fcu_protocol)"/>
    <!-- load blacklist, config -->
    <rosparam file="$(arg pluginlists_yaml)"/>
    <rosparam file="$(arg config_yaml)"/>
</node>

How do I proceed?
